# Display custom taxonomy posts of custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type "Portfolio" and a custom taxonomy "Kind" which includes "Websites", "Graphics", "Programming".

What I want to do is to create 3 different pages "Websites", "Graphics" etc. that will display the appropriate items as a list.

This is my code to display "Portfolio" posts :

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio') ); ?>
    <?php if( is_tax() ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $title = $term->name;
    }  ?>

            <div id="content" class="clearfix">
                <div id="main" class="clearfix" role="main">
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $categories = get_the_category(); ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix single-post'); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                        <header>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?>
                            <div class="page-header"><h3 itemprop="headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></div>
                        </header> <!-- end article header -->

                        <section class="post_content clearfix">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </section>

                        <!--<footer>
                            </footer>--> <!-- end article footer -->

                    </article> <!-- end article -->

                    <?php endwhile; ?>          
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div> <!-- end #main -->    
            </div> <!-- end #content -->
```

Unfortunately, I can't manage to display only "graphics" or "websites" posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create taxonomy archives, not pages.

Create three separate files called

```
taxonomy-kind-websites.php
taxonomy-kind-graphics.php
taxonomy-kind-programming.php
```

Displaying the items/posts as a list is pretty simple, eg

```
<ul class="my-posts">       
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  </li>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

You may also need to add the following to your arguments

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'kind')
```

when you register your taxonomy

Update:
Have a look at http://kovshenin.com/2012/how-to-add-taxonomies-to-your-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/ on how to add custom taxonomies to custom post types. I would, however, not create a new post type but instead a category called  "Portfolio" and then create a single post template for this category, called `single-portfolio.php`, where you can customize the design easily. You can then further customize by replacing the call `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>` with your own `<?php get_template_part( 'custom', 'single' ); ?>`.

Comment: and how do I display only "websites" from taxonomy "Kind" ?

Comment: Include the loop above inside `taxonomy-kind-websites.php` and then simply visit the taxonomy term archive and the posts with the term 'website' selected will display. You will find the url by clicking "view" under Posts > Kind > Websites in the admin area.

Comment: Do you mean that wordpress picks up the name of taxonomy from the filename automatically ? In case of "taxonomy-kind-website.php" wordpress sees "website" ?

Comment: Sorry I just deleted a comment. The terms aren't registered but created from the admin area of course. Make sure the term name is 'websites' if the file is `taxonomy-kind-websites.php`

Comment: Yes, excactly, Wordpress gets the posts belonging to the "website" term if you have created the template `taxonomy-kind-website.php`.

Comment: and if you create a `taxonomy-kind.php` template, posts from all terms in the taxonomy will be shown: "Websites", "Graphics" and "Programming".

Comment: this sounds awesome. I can't believe it was that simple! But who do I connect the menu item with the taxonomy ? I mean, what I was going to do was to create 3 pages for each taxonomy item and attach them to menu.

Comment: It will depend on your permalink structure - for instance by selecting "Day and name", you should get a pretty url www.mysite.com/kind/website/. To get the taxonomy terms you can use something like `$terms = get_terms("my_taxonomy");
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0 ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";
        
     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). I suggest you call a custom header from your custom taxonomy templates where you can add the items to a menu.

Comment: See updated answer regarding custom post type.

Comment: I am a little bit confused reading your explanation. My hierarchy is: Portfolio(post type) => Kind => websites/graphics/programming

Comment: My permalink structure is "Post name". I am unable to view taxonomy's items by going to www.website.dev/Portfolio or /Kind

Comment: Hi again, I haven't tried this but should be straightforward to first add an already registered taxonomy to a custom post type: `register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'kind', 'portfolio' );` The link I provided in my updated answer explains this in more detail. You will not see the taxonomy terms from the Portfolio type since they belong to the Kind taxonomy, from where you should be able to view them. The permalink settings shouldn't matter only that you have created the taxonomy templates described above.